# How can I seperate all the numbers from a string as indicated?

Tags: python, list

So I'm gonna write a code for a bigger program but I'm stuck on this issue. The input for my program is going to be a string like this `s="cycling;time:1,49;distance:2"` and what I want to do let the program return only the numbers in the provided string. I found how to do that as well like this...

```
def getDigits(s):
    answer = []
    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit():
            answer.append(char)
    return ''.join(answer)

print(getDigits(s="cycling;time:1,49;distance:2"))
```

However, even though the output prints out `1492` , I want it to print it out seperately.. so basically I want to let my program print out 1,49 seperately from 2 because 1,49 is the cycling time while 2 is the distance (according to the string input itself). What changes to my code should I make?

**Edit:** my expected output would be like this...
the cycling time values and the distance values are gonna be grouped differently

##### Expected Output:-

```
(149) (2)
```

Comment: Use a regex:  `import re; re.findall('[\d,]+', s)`

Comment: Its part of a college assignment and I'm not allowed to use import lol, so yea. I'll use the data from this piece of code to run another program as well btw

Comment: Please add your expected o/p. Looks like your list join having the problem

Comment: @VikasP I have edited and added my expected output

Comment: Use [str.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) to split on semicolon, then for all fields split again on colon and if there is a second field convert it to a number using the `float()` function. Also you might want to explain what the meaning of the `,` in `1,49` is. Is that a decimal separator or a group separator?

Comment: @heijp06 its like a group seperator, so in other words 1,49 is like 1 hour 49 minutes

Comment: Then don't use the `float()` function. Just treat what ever you get after splitting on colon as a string.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC here is a simple one-liner to solve that, it will return a list of the values (including the comma):

```py
def get_digits(s):
    return [data.split(':')[1] for data in s.split(';') if ':' in data]


print(get_digits(s="cycling;time:1,49;distance:2"))

# Output:
# ['1,49', '2']
```

Expanded it looks like this:

```py
def get_digits(s):
    answer = []
    # iterate over the split string
    for data in s.split(';'):
        # check if semicolon is in that string so
        # that when splitting there is a second value
        if ':' in data:
            # append the second item when splitting by colon
            answer.append(data.split(':')[1])
    return answer
```

Useful:

- [`str.split` (with examples)](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it like @heijp06 already mentioned it.

```
def getDigits(s):
  answer = []
  t = '(' + s.split(';')[1].split(':')[1] + ')'
  d = '(' + s.split(';')[2].split(':')[1] + ')'
  return ''.join((t,d))
```

Comment: While the "expected output" contains the characters you are trying to print, this is typically intended to be the representation of a Python tuple, so the function should rather output that, instead of its representation.

Answer (score 0):

Do some minor changes. Split with ";", then loop:

```
def getDigits(s):
    answer = []
    for char in s.split(";"):
        k = ""
        for split_s in char:
            if split_s.isdigit():
                k += split_s
        if k:
            answer.append(k)
    return answer


print(getDigits(s="cycling;time:1,49;distance:2"))
```

Output :

```
['149', '2']
```

Comment: hey, I was just wondering, if like there are decimal places involved in the string as well, how can I let python print out like decimals exactly the same like they were from the input. Because for instance when distance : 2.89, it prints as 289 and ignores the decimal point, how can that be fixed?

Comment: thank u for taking ur time off and answering my question btw :)